# "Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined" I believe I've defined e

Tags: ajax, referenceerror

I get an error in the console saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined" The button I am clicking has the name "sendtxt". I made sure it has function(e) on it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $('input[name="sendtxt"]').click(function(e) {
            sendText();
        });

    });
    /************ FUNCTIONS ******************/

    function sendText() {
        e.preventDefault();
        var phonenum = $('input[name="phonenum"]').val();
        var provider = $('select[name="provider"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                provider: provider,
                phonenum: phonenum
            },
            url: 'send.php',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Success');

            },
            error: function(xhr, err) {
                console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing on `e`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="sendtxt"]').click(function(e) {
        sendText(e);  // <<<
    });
});
/************ FUNCTIONS ******************/

function sendText(e) {    // <<<
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

---

But really, that's easier written as:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="sendtxt"]').click(sendText);
});
/************ FUNCTIONS ******************/

function sendText(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

jQuery event handlers expect a function, and `sendText` is a function. No need to wrap it in *another* function.

Comment: Happens to all of us. ;)

Comment: some borwsers still need return false. use two of them, at least at the end of your event code.